# HTTP Chunked response error handling

Tags: java, http, http-headers, netty

I'm building a web app that chunk outputs back to the client in Java netty.

I've read and searched the internet and found the following resources:

- [HTTP Made Really Easy](http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/#http1.1c2)
- [Error code redirect when returning a response with chunked encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707291/error-code-redirect-when-returning-a-response-with-chunked-encoding)
- [HTTP 1.1 RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)

and to summarize, I am lead to believe that trailer-headers with "Location" should be respected regardless of the http response and or prior headers.

However after some blackbox testing on Firefox and Chrome. Neither browser respects the trailing header.

So my question is

- first of all have I missed something?
- Secondly, what would be the ideal solution to deal with errors in chunked response?

  - I am only currently aware of using javascripts in the middle of a response.
- and finally, am I wrong in believing HTTP Location headers should be respected regardless of http response code? The specification as I linked above made no mention it must be 3xx headers and in fact mentioned 201 headers as a possible case for Location as well but none of the major browsers respect it.

Comment: Yes, you are wrong to think Location should be respected for every status code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, UAs (AFAIK) do not support trailers.

Second, the semantics of Location depend on the status code. What do you *think* should happen with a Location header field upon a status 200???

Comment: If it is a trailer header, to respect the header. Otherwise why have the tailer header in the spec specifically for chunking? The use case as I presented is perfectly legal in order to build a speedy web service that prints outputs as soon as it's ready.

Comment: Ronald, I agree it's unfortunate that UAs do not implement trailers.

That being said, what do *you* think *is* the right thing to do with Location in 200 responses, independently of where it appears??? And where's the spec backing this?

Comment: While Location is required for 201 and can be included with many of the 3XX status codes, I think @Julian is trying to get you to see that it doesn't make sense to claim that a UA should follow Location for every status code.  If a GET results in a 200, then the requested resource is in the response.  The Location header makes no sense and should be ignored.  The same is true for many other status codes.

Comment: what James said (except for Location being required on 201; not true that is).

Comment: Are you sure, @Julian?  "The newly created resource can be referenced by the URI(s) returned in the entity of the response, with the most specific URI for the resource given by a Location header field."  I suppose it doesn't say "MUST" but it sure sounds like it expects the Location header to exist in a 201.  (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2.2)  Shiflett says Location is required (p72); Gourley/Totty says the URL should be in Location (p61).

Comment: James, what's relevant is the RFC. Requiring Location doesn't make sense for PUT responses, for example.

Comment: It makes perfect sense.  Request says put a file here.  Server creates the file, returns 201, and gives location.  Why location?  Because it might create the file but have to put it there instead, if here isn't viable.  Location is how the server confirms to the client where it put the file, whether here or there.

Comment: James, nope. If the server can't PUT the file at the request URI, it shouldn't return 201 but fail the request. 201 implies success, and putting the file somewhere else isn't what the client asked for.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, bad example.  Shoulda thought that one through.  Don't listen to my scenario above, peeps!  (Still doesn't mean Location isn't required, just redundant.)

Comment: Regardless of the status code. One thing is obvious. If chunking is supposed to be the next extension of HTTP, it needs to cater for errors encountered as a server/application chunks responses back to the UA and to me, it makes sense to terminate the response when an error is encountered and send a new status code back to the UA. That was entirely the reason why I started this thread.

Comment: Current workarounds as I said involves either sending back a javascript to do on-screen manipulation to show an error has encountered to the user, which is a big no no. Hence I've given up on chunking responses for now. Which is a shame when technologies are abound that deals with non-blocking IOs and asynchronous responses. HTTP remains a serial text transfer protocol that cannot handle errors occurring half way between transmission.

Comment: Ronald: chunking as specified in the HTTP spec doesn't allow you changing the status code once the first line of the response is sent.